# Pie chart how to sum values when labels are the same

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made this.

```
query = "SELECT towar, sztuki, zysk FROM sklep"
mycr.execute(query)
wyniki = mycr.fetchall()
nazwy = []
sztuki = []
for a in wyniki:
 nazwy.append(a[0])
 sztuki.append(a[1])
plt.pie(sztuki, labels=nazwy, autopct='%.1f%%')
plt.show()
```

[image] 
Everythink works fine but how to sum percentages when labels are the same?
For example how to sum percentages of "woda" labels?

Comment: I'd prefer to use dictionaries.

Comment: @saad_saeed can you tell me how?

Comment: Sure, check answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer to use dictionaries. In your case, nazwy is the key (labels) and sztuki are the values stored in dictionary. Here is your modified code:

```
query = "SELECT towar, sztuki, zysk FROM sklep"
mycr.execute(query)
wyniki = mycr.fetchall()
data_dict = {}
for a in wyniki:
    if a[0] in data_dict.keys():
        data_dict[a[0]] = data_dict[a[0]]+a[1]
    else:
        data_dict[a[0]] = a[1]

nazwy = list(data_dict.keys())
sztuki = list(data_dict.values())
# plotting
plt.pie(sztuki, labels=nazwy, autopct='%.1f%%')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you explain for me that if statement?

Comment: It checks for the existence of label in dictionary dynamically. If it already exists it adds current value to previous value by ```current_value = previous_value+current_value``` else it creates a new label in dictionary with current_value. You can read more about dictionaries [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

Comment: Also check this [example](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/how-to-check-if-a-key-exists-in-a-dictionary/)